# Connect from python3 - pyodbc (linux) to a firebird 2.5 (windows) ODBC DSN on remote machine

Tags: python-3.x, odbc, firebird, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to a customer's DB via ODBC. The ODBC DSN was setup on the the Windows machine. I don't know the path to the DB or the DB name so I have to rely on the DSN.

From what I've seen in general this does not seem to be possible, but I know Pervasive ODBC allows it and seems like MSSQL also allows it.

Question is, does Firebird 2.5 allow this? If it does could you please help me with the connection string

I've set up a Firebird DB on a local windows machine, created an ODBC DSN (and tested the connection locally).

I then tested connections from unixODBC (isql) and python pyodbc and they all connect fine, but I have to specify DB location and name and credentials.

I need to connect to the remote (windows) Firebird ODBC DSN from python 3.6 pyodbc (linux)

Comment: if you go our of Firebird into ODBC realm - there can be no question "if Firebird allows it". Now you have to look into questions like "are there programs/services that share local ODBC sources into network, like Remote Registry shares registry, like Remote folder shares folder, is their some kind of Remote ODBC". Since you say u have to specify credentials - you use Firebird networking, and your Linux box connects by Firebird protocols, and then inside Linux box it is converted into Python API or Linux ODBC API, etc. Perhaps you better connect with pyFDB or some other FDB-targeting library

Comment: what is your real problem? Concealing the filename is not hard - see `aliases.conf` in Firebird folder. But login and password would have to be specified. Otherwise, any anonymous (rogue) program would be able to connect w/o credentials to your Firebird server and make a DOS attack, for example overflowing the Windows computer disk.

Comment: Arioch, thank you for the reply.
The tests I've done have been from unixODBC to firebird directly. So it does not hit the ODBC DSN on the remote machine. I don't have access to the credentials or location so I have to use the DSN on the remote machine, which has been saved with the credentials and location of the DB.
I'll have a look at pyFDB and see if that can connect to the remote DSN

Comment: I know next to nothing about ODBC, but common sense applies. Either we work within realms of one protocol - or another. Either we download files - maybe same very files - via HTTP or FTP or SMB. And while files are the same, and maybe even usernames, but protocols are different. Same should be about ODBC and Firebird - either remote connection is made within one protocol or another. However, anonymous free-for-all remote connection ( without any credentials ) is hardly a desired configuration anyway. DB filename can be checked in DSN properties. Login/pwd maybe can b extracted somehow by API?

Comment: I agree with the credentials issue. It is saved in the DSN, so yes, that does actually open things up for abuse IF you could connect from a remote machine through the DSN. Actually not a good way to go about it at all. Will relay this to the customer.
For my own sanity, can you connect to a remote Firebird ODBC DSN?

Comment: I don't use ODBC, frankly it does not look like ODBC or .Net are the most popular connection methods in Firebird-centric community. Also, what I say, is that this question seems to either be not about ODBC or not about Firebird. If you connect by FB protocol - there is no ODBC in picture. If you, however, connect to the ODBC DSN, the ODBC "service", then there is no Firebird in picture. It would get encapsulated and abstracted out. If you can organize remote access in purely ODBC terms, then it should not matter what DB lies behind the DSN locally: FB, Oracle, FoxPro DBF or anything.

Comment: maybe you would need some connection helper application running on the target Windows computer and providing credential by request to your Linux-box application. See https://security.stackexchange.com/a/138287/207216 maybe applicable to FB ODBC too.

Comment: An ODBC DSN is just a connection specification, and it can only be used from the machine that contains that ODBC DSN. If you want to use it from a different machine, you will have to define an equivalent ODBC DSN on that machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want isn't possible*. An ODBC DSN exists only on the machine where it is defined. It is basically a connection configuration that is decoupled from your application, and your application references the configuration by a name.

You can't use a DSN remotely (if that were possible, that would be a pretty big security leak). You will need to define a DSN (or use a DSN-less connection string), on your specific machine to be able to use it from that machine.

Given you're using Python, consider using FDB or pyfirebirdsql instead of using pyODBC.

---

* Or at least, not possible without some middleware service on the remote machine that mediates between your application and the ODBC DSN on the remote machine.

Comment: Thanks Mark. From all the digging I've done I've come to the same conclusion, but needed to confirm.